# Regex Java Illegal/unsupported escape sequence

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm searching for a "color=number,number,number" and get the "number,number,number" part using regex but when I put the regex pattern,

I get:
*Regular expression '"\bcolor=\b\K\w\d*,\d*,\d*"' is malformed: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence*

Here is the code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bcolor=\\b\\K\\w\\d*,\\d*,\\d*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    if(m.find()){
        return m.group(0);
    }
    else {
        return "0,0,0";
    }
```

I also tried:

```
    "\\bcolor=\\b\\\\K\\w\\d*,\\d*,\\d*"
```

and:

```
    "\\\\bcolor=\\\\b\\\\K\\\\w\\\\d*,\\\\d*,\\\\d*"
```

The above compiles but doesn't get the desired result.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does Java even support `\K`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`\K` match reset  operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) is not supported by the regex engine in Android. You can safely use a capturing group around the part of the regex you want to extract and then grab it using `.group(1)`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bcolor=(\\w\\d*,\\d*,\\d*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if(m.find()){
    return m.group(1);
}
else {
    return "0,0,0";
}
```

Note you do not need the second `\b` word boundary as it is implicit between a `=` (non-word char) and `\w` (matches a word char).

**Details**

- `\bcolor=` - `color=` as a whole word
- `(\w\d*,\d*,\d*)` - Capturing group #1: a word char, 0+ digits, and 2 occurrences `,` followed with `,` and 0+ digits. You may even write it as `(\\w\\d*(?:,\\d*){2})`.